# The type of one of the expression in th Join Clause is Incorrect. Type Inference failed in call to group Join

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Please review my Linq Query and suggest the fix. THe second Join is giving error.

```
 var result = (from e in _DB_Goal_Allocation.Employees.Where(x => x.Active == 1 && x.Branch_Number == ddlBranch)
                          join j in _DB_Goal_Allocation.Employees_JobTitleGroupLOBs.Where(y => Job_Group.Contains(y.JobGroup)) on e.Title equals j.JobTitle
                          join g in _DB_Goal_Allocation.Goal_Allocation_Employees.Where(ga => ga.Year == ddlYear)
                          on new{ e.Branch_Number, e.EmployeeID } equals new { Branch_Number = g.BranchNumber, EmployeeID = g.EmployeeID } into emp
                          from t in emp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName as EmployeeName).ToList();
```

Comment: Well what are the types involved (e.Branch_Number, g.BranchNumber, e.EmployeeID, g.EmployeeID)? We can't help you without any more information...

Comment: Branch_number is nullable int  and BranchNumber int  and both EmployeeID  are  int

Comment: Right, well that's the problem then. You need to cast BranchNumber to `Nullable<int>`. The types have to match *exactly* for a join.

Comment: I have not even think of the nullable thing before u asked. Thanks a lot!! It worked.